# API call Trustpilot

Tags: api, trustpilot

I'm trying to send invitation link through our own system and use the API call to get invitation link.

I have received the TOKEN but now have problems when I try with API call to get invitation link.
Get the error "403"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the API key as well as the token?

Add this header to the request:
`apikey: [YOUR_API_KEY]`

For context, here is the documentation.
https://developers.trustpilot.com/invitation-api#generate-service-review-invitation-link